# Running Java computations on the GPU on an m1 Mac?

Tags: java, gpu

I develop and run scientific computations in java on my MacBook Pro. I'd like to start learning gpu programming in java so I can optimize some of my pipelines. Ideally I can start with a high-level library but if I have to do something lower-level, I will.

I first tried https://aparapi.com, but it is not yet compatible with the new Macs (got incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e') when trying to link the native library (I have shared this with the developer of the library so they are aware). Tensorflow-GPU for java doesn't yet have a release for the m1 Macs. Someone supposedly compiled and shared some jars with tensorflow-gpu for java that is compatible with new Macs, but they did not compile for me (I made an issue here). I did some more searching, and found https://github.com/mxmlnkn/rootbeer1 and https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JavaCL but both of these are very old and surely not compatible with the new Mac. Is time for me to stop my search and wait for the library developers to catch up, or is there more I can try now?